# error during zabbix 3.2 compile

Tags: php, compiler-errors, zabbix

I am trying to compile zabbix 3.2 .I want to install it with db2 database

during the installation I pass the "./configure" step with my options

```
./configure --enable-server --with-ssh2 --enable-agent --with-libcurl --with-libxml2  --with-ibm-db2 --with-unixodbc --with-ibm-db2-lib=/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/lib64/ --with-ibm-db2-include=/opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/ --prefix=/MY_ADDRESS/zabbix
```

but when i run "make" the out put is giving me this error :

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/tmp/zabbix/zabbix-3.2.2/src/libs/zbxdbhigh'
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../include    -I../../../src/zabbix_server/ -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT libzbxdbhigh_a-host.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/libzbxdbhigh_a-host.Tpo -c -o libzbxdbhigh_a-host.o `test -f 'host.c' || echo './'`host.c
mv -f .deps/libzbxdbhigh_a-host.Tpo .deps/libzbxdbhigh_a-host.Po
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../include    -I../../../src/zabbix_server/ -I/usr/include -g -O2 -MT libzbxdbhigh_a-odbc.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/libzbxdbhigh_a-odbc.Tpo -c -o libzbxdbhigh_a-odbc.o `test -f 'odbc.c' || echo './'`odbc.c
In file included from ../../../include/zbxodbc.h:24,
                 from odbc.c:25:
/usr/include/sqlext.h:30: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQLSTATE’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1745: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1863: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1880: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1889: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1904: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1916: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1925: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1946: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1949: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1959: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1964: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1969: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1981: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:1996: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2010: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2016: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2028: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2042: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2115: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2126: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2133: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2134: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2135: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2142: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2152: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2153: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2163: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
/usr/include/sqlext.h:2175: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SQL_API’
odbc.c: In function ‘odbc_Diag’:
odbc.c:87: error: ‘SQL_ERROR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:87: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
odbc.c:87: error: for each function it appears in.)
odbc.c:90: error: ‘SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:93: error: ‘SQL_NO_DATA’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:96: error: ‘SQL_INVALID_HANDLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:99: error: ‘SQL_STILL_EXECUTING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:102: error: ‘SQL_NEED_DATA’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:105: error: ‘SQL_SUCCESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c: In function ‘odbc_DBclose’:
odbc.c:141: error: ‘SQL_HANDLE_STMT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:150: error: ‘SQL_HANDLE_DBC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:156: error: ‘SQL_HANDLE_ENV’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c: In function ‘odbc_DBconnect’:
odbc.c:176: error: ‘SQL_HANDLE_ENV’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:176: error: ‘SQL_NULL_HANDLE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:183: error: ‘SQL_SUCCESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:183: error: ‘SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:183: error: ‘SQL_OV_ODBC3’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:190: error: ‘SQL_HANDLE_DBC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:205: error: ‘SQL_NTS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:212: error: ‘SQL_HANDLE_STMT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:235: error: ‘SQL_DBMS_NAME’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:241: error: ‘SQL_DBMS_VER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c: In function ‘odbc_DBfetch’:
odbc.c:280: error: ‘SQL_NO_DATA’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:286: error: ‘SQL_SUCCESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:286: error: ‘SQL_HANDLE_STMT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:298: error: ‘SQL_DESC_TYPE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:307: error: ‘SQL_WLONGVARCHAR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:311: error: ‘SQL_CHAR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:323: error: ‘SQL_NULL_DATA’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c: In function ‘odbc_DBselect’:
odbc.c:357: error: ‘SQL_SUCCESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:357: error: ‘SQL_NTS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
odbc.c:357: error: ‘SQL_HANDLE_STMT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[3]: *** [libzbxdbhigh_a-odbc.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/tmp/zabbix/zabbix-3.2.2/src/libs/zbxdbhigh'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/zabbix/zabbix-3.2.2/src/libs'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/zabbix/zabbix-3.2.2/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

i think this problem is related on my php installation but i can not find the solution

tnks .

Comment: Is it possible to compile with IBM DB2, but without UnixODBC?

Comment: It seems that there is already an issue about that, see [ZBX-10576](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-10576).

Comment: i run my "./configure" command without "--with-unixodbc" and the error dont show during installation

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: but i can not understand why?

Comment: You may wish to add your story to [ZBX-10576](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-10576).